# Cannot connect to internet in Vbox?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet-explorer-7

I have configured a Windows XP VM to connect to the Internet . However, even after checking the configuration, it doesn't work on IE7. Can someone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 1):

IE 7 is long deprecated.  Try IE 8. Or,download Chrome for XP (perhaps on a different machine and transfer it).  I have an XP virtual machine here and Chrome works well. IE 8 works also.

Ping 8.8.8.8 and ensure your basic network connection is working.

Comment: I used IE7 because that's what came with my version of WinXP. BTW I'm using Version 2004, MediaCentre Edition, Service Pack Three.

Comment: I upgraded my XP machine to IE8